# Run randbetween function n times in a cell where n = the result of a randbetween function in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I write a formula in Excel 2013 to conduct the randbetween function n times in a cell where n is equal to the value of another cell?

For example, I have cell A2 calculating randbetween(1,10) and it returns a value of 6. How do I have cell B2 conduct randbetween (1,8) six times and show the values of each calculation so I have six numbers, each between 1 and 8?  The results in B2, optimally would show something like 8, 6, 5, 4,6, 7 (if the randbetween in A2 gives a result of 6).

Comment: and what would the output look like?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013.

Comment: to get the array comma(,) delimited you will need vba or many helper columns.

Comment: I don't have an issue with using VBA (other than I'm not too familiar with how I'd write it).

Comment: The main issue is that most will not write it for you.  This site is more about helping overcome a specific problem with existing code.  There are those that will write it, but you may be waiting a while.  Better to try it yourself, or find a UDF that mimics TEXTJOIN() like this one here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell and use `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,RANDBETWEEN(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2))^0,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2))^0+7))` As an array formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one does not have the `RANDARRAY` function described in @Excellll's [Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1553560/run-randbetween-function-n-times-in-a-cell-where-n-the-result-of-a-randbetween/1553568#1553568) we can use SUMPRODUCT and an array formula:

Put this in B2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RANDBETWEEN(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2))^0,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2))^0+7)*10^(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2))-1))
```

This may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

If one has office 2019 which has `CONCAT` but not `RANDARRAY` we can do it in one cell:

```
=CONCAT(RANDBETWEEN(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2))^0,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2))^0+7))
```

This may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Office 365:

You can use the `RANDARRAY` function to do this. Each random number output by the function will be in a different cell.

For example, if `A2` is the number of random numbers you need, you could put the following in `B2`.

```
=RANDARRAY(1,A2,1,8,TRUE)
```

This will create 6 random integers between 1 and 8 and spill them across the range `B2:G2`.

Comment: One note to be added, `RANDARRAY` is only available with an office 365 subscription.  Older versions will not have this formula.

Comment: Tried the formula as you posted.  All I got was a #NAME? error.  I'm using Excel 2013, so that might be why.

Comment: @spydercoll Yes, RANDARRAY is a new function. It won't be recognized in older versions of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function MultiRand(times As Long, bottom As Long, top As Long) As String
    Application.Volatile
    Dim i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    MultiRand = ""
    For i = 1 To times
        MultiRand = MultiRand & CStr(wf.RandBetween(bottom, top))
    Next i
End Function
```

An example of its use:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>  brings up the VBE window
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=MultiRand(A1,A2,A3)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation, one example: `=RANDBETWEEN(1,8)&", "&RANDBETWEEN(1,8)`